# Como obtengo una imagen de vista previa desde el ID de un vídeo de Facebook

Tags: facebook

necesito obtener la imagen de vista previa en grande de los vídeos de facebook a través de su id (por ejemplo: 590572521150032)

Encontré esta forma pero me da la imagen muy pequeña y yo la necesito mas grande:

https://graph.facebook.com/590572521150032/picture

Answer (score 1):

Quizás no sea la respuesta que busca pero la imágen que traes con graph es el archivo de miniatura (es para mostrar en la página, y es lo que hay), si quieres poner algo mas grande pues deberías poner directamente el video como vista previa en tu web con un iframe, de la siguiente forma

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fvideolocos%2Fvideos%2F1004292302990557%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Podrías poner un evento click, de manera que al hacer click en play como para reproducir pues vaya al video o al lugar que quieres. de esa manera tienes también como una vista previa, solo que con el botón de play encima.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes obtener la imagen más grande, pero si puedes obtener los thumbnails, para lograrlo debes ejecutarlo desde el graph api.

[Aquí la documentación](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]